# How can I tell which one of these numbers is greater?

Tags: summation, exponentiation

I have two very large numbers how do I tell which one is greater. The two numbers are $$\sum^{9(10^{99}) } _{i=1}i^9$$
and

$9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9^{9}}}}}}}}}$

Comment: What do you mean of E99?

Comment: 9E99 = 9*(10^99)

Comment: It is scientific notation like your calculator might give you if it gets a really large number.

Comment: Your sum is less than 9E99 times $(9E99)^9$.  This should give you a start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power tower is much larger. Note that you have to solve it from above.

So, you start with $9^9$ . Then you take $9$ to the power of that number and so on. If you are at $9\uparrow 9\uparrow 9\uparrow 9$, you will have left the sum in the dust because it is smaller than $(9\times 10^{99})\times (9\times 10^{99})^9=(9\times 10^{99})^{10}=9^{10}\times 10^{990}$

Comment: OK, cool. That was easier than I thought it would be. I completely forgot that  I can multiply all of the exponents together to end up with 9^387420489 which is obviously greater than that summation.

Comment: Actually you only multiply the exponents together if you have something like $(...((9^9)^9)...^9)$, so that you exponentiate from left to right.  For a power tower you exponentiate from right to left, yielding a much larger number.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum^{9\times10^{99} } _{i=1}i^9 <\sum^{9\times10^{99} } _{i=1} \left( 9\times10^{99}\right)^9=\left( 9\times10^{99}\right)^{10}<9^{2000}$$

OP can you take it from here? Hint: $9^9>2000$